# Stream video to android devices over wifi

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I have to develop an app which is suppose to stream video to other device using WiFi (without Internet ). User should be able to select a video file from first device and stream in second device.
I don't have any clear idea on how to send data  to another device (specially video ). Are there any steaming libraries available for android where to strwam the video ?

Please help me to find a solution to my problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you got any approch for this problem?

Have you gone through this how to share the files using wifi direct method.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Thanks
Mohsin